# Why is my data not rendering even though I am clearly getting a result from my console output?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, supabase

I am getting data from supabase and passing it as a prop then using the usual map to iterate over the data and display the values I need. But for some reason I can't get it to display. I thought `getServerSideProps` returned the data before the page gets rendered. I get the correct results on my `console.log(programme.title)` but nothing gets rendered.

```
import React from 'react'
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js'

export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const supabase = createClient(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL!, process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY!)
    const { data: programmes, error }: any = await supabase
            .from('Programmes')
            .select('*')
  
    return {
      props: {
        programmes,
      },
    }
}

function programmes({programmes}: any) {

  return (
    <>
        <div className='mx-auto px-12'>
            <div className='my-24  flex flex-col'>
                <h1 className='font-extrabold text-5xl'>Les programmes Natyf</h1>
                <p>Actualités, films dramatiques, comédies, documentaires, talk-shows, spectacles de variétés et d’humour hauts en couleurs et en saveurs!</p>
            </div>

            {programmes.map((programme: any) => {
                <div>          
                    {console.log(programme.title)}
                    <div className="max-w-sm bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-lg shadow dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img className="rounded-t-lg" src="/docs/images/blog/image-1.jpg" alt="" />
                        </a>
                        <div className="p-5">
                            <h5 className="text-xl tracking-tight text-transparent bg-clip-text bg-gradient-to-r from-cyan-500 to-blue-500">{programme.show_time}</h5>
                            <h2 className='text-2xl font-bold text-white'>{programme.title}</h2>
                            <p className="my-4 font-normal text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">{programme.description}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            })}

       </div>
    </>
    
  )
}

export default programmes
```

At first I had tried making a function that returns my data from supabase and calling that function via `useEffect()` but I quickly realized my object was empty at render so I switched to using `getServerSideProps`

Comment: When you say `nothing gets rendered` do you mean that even `divs` surrounding `{programme.title}` are not rendered?

Comment: Assuming 1) "_but nothing gets rendered_" means the data from your `programmes` object (ie. the image shows up - right?), 2) your intent is to render server side. If so, there is nothing wrong with your code. The only **?** is the CSS. What happens if you remove the CSS completely?

Comment: Exactly. The divs are not rendering.

Comment: I suspect the divs are rending - but perhaps the text is not visible or not there. When you look at the _Elements_ tab in the browser developer tools - what do you see? Do you see `<body></body>` do you see empty `divs` with no text or something else?

Comment: Create a codesandbox or stackblitz that exactly replicates your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. Had to change the brackets to parenthesis

Before:

```
{programmes.map((programme: any) => {...}
```

After:

```
{programmes.map((programme: any) => (...)
```

Hope this helps someone in the futur. So stupid it got overlooked.